# How to save database information to a file in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an application that uses a pre-polulated database to list events.  The app allows people to save these events to their favorites by setting a '1' to the column isFavorite.  Then the user can view only a list of 'favorited' events which searches for all rows that have isFavorite = 1.

If any changes happen to the events or I need to add more to the list, I have to make those changes and then push the update to the app which completely writes over the table, clearing out their favorites.

Is there any way that I can, on upgrade, save a list of id's of all the events that they have set to their favorites, then after the new database has been loaded, to set all id's in that list to 1 so the user doesn't lose their favorited data?

If there are any other better solutions to this problem I would really appreciate it, this has been the biggest hurdle for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you have a [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)-class? This class must be extended and then provides two functions: `onCreate` (which is called when the Database is queried and it doesn't exist (Normally creates your Database in the first place)) and `onUpdate` (which is queried when the Database structure should be updated).

The `onUpdate`-method has an `SQLiteDatabase`-Object parameter, which is your Database. You can then Query the information you need, save them and then create the new Database-tables. After that, you can insert your saved data back into the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you cope with thus in your DB design? Have a user favourites table that holds id's. So long as these id's don't change upgrade won't affect it surely?

Comment: I'm not too versed in Android/SQL design but my current setup includes a prepopulated SQL database file that is loaded into the assets folder, if the app needs an update, it deletes the active database and re-imports the updated database using the new file, which effectively clears all the users data that they would have changed at that point.  I'm sure this isn't the best method by any means but I haven't found any other way to do it yet.

Comment: Right - so why not have a "User" db, which you can use the versioning capabilities to upgrade when required?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is backing up part or all of your database to restore at a later time. I found this guide quite handy **http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7749**

Alternatively, you may save their favorites as a SharedPreferences. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html for more information on that.