# Cannot find table on first run

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an Android program I am writing that contains a database.  On the first run it copies the database from the APK into the program's data directory.  If I perform a query after that I get this error:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: dictionary: , while compiling:

I don't get this error on subsequent queries.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to copy the database?

Answer (score 0):

A database shouldn't be copied, you should create a `SQLiteOpenHelper`-class and use it to create/update your Database and insert some standard-values. Check out [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051229/how-to-save-database-information-to-a-file-in-android/6051312#6051312) of mine.

Comment: I followed this blog: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ are you advising against this?

Comment: Jop, I've seen this one often here. Copying the Database is a bad practice. You should really use the `SQLiteOpenHelper` as Google itself recommends it: [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)